# Select data from multiple tables with same column names and structure using sql

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function

I am get data from a third party database to generate certain reports. The issue is that it keeps on generating a new table every month to insert the same record in same columns in the following manner:

```
For December table : Data_12_2019
For January table  : Data_1_2020
For February table : Data_2_2020
For March table    : Data_3_2020 and so on
```

and table data is as following:

```
UserId  DLogId  LogDate
1461    1799    2020-01-06 09:07:51.000
1462    1803    2020-01-07 09:29:39.000
1463    1806    2020-01-07 11:43:11.000
1464    1807    2020-01-09 09:16:47.000
1457    1819    2020-01-10 09:00:56.000
```

table2

```
UserId  DLogId  LogDate
1466    1853    2020-02-03 09:11:54.000
1468    1831    2020-02-04 09:17:09.000
1470    1833    2020-02-5 09:01:06.000
```

and need output in a single table in following manner:

```
UserId  DLogId  LogDate
1461    1799    2020-01-06 09:07:51.000
1462    1803    2020-01-07 09:29:39.000
1463    1806    2020-01-07 11:43:11.000
1464    1807    2020-01-09 09:16:47.000
1457    1819    2020-01-10 09:00:56.000
1466    1853    2020-02-03 09:11:54.000
1468    1831    2020-02-04 09:17:09.000
1470    1833    2020-02-5 09:01:06.000
```

I want to get data placed in above tables and tables that will be generated in future also.
I am seeking a help about how to do it.

Comment: You should include the sample data, expected output in the table format with the details of logic in your question and also what you are trying and how it different from the expected output?

Comment: sound like you will need to use `dynamic sql`. Do a search on this, there are lots of information available

Comment: I'm not sure who closed this for not being focused.  Perhaps the moderator didn't understand this very focused question because there is a bit of a language barrier thing going on here.  It's a real shame that it was closed to answers because I'm pretty sure I understand the question and do have the answer.  I've done such a thing tens of times.  Would you please reopen this post so I can answer it?

Comment: @Anshdeep Singh ... It would appear that the moderators didn't understand your question and so made it that people that do cannot reply with any further answers.  Post your question on SQLServerCentral.com and one of us will answer it with code.  The thing that you're looking for (I believe) is a "partitioned view".  PSK came real close to it below.

Comment: I am very disappointed, at-least one should issue some sort warning before closing the question. Dale K, Suraj Kumar, Squirrel.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using dynamic query. If your table structure is same, you can try like following.

```
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ' ' + 'SELECT * FROM ' + Quotename(name) + ' UNION' 
                 FROM   
                 (
                  SELECT 
                    [name]
                FROM
                    sys.sysobjects
                WHERE
                    [xtype] = 'U'
                    and NAME LIKE 'Data_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
                 )t
                 FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''); 

SET @query= substring(@query,0,len(@query)-5)
exec(@query)
```

**Note**: Better replace * with the column names you want.

To get all the tables you can use `sysobject` and filter out based on table names like

```
SELECT [name]
FROM sys.sysobjects
WHERE [xtype] = 'U'
    AND NAME LIKE 'Data_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

And build a dynamic query using `UNION`.

Comment: PSK , can you please elaborate the above solution

Comment: @AnshdeepSingh, what exactly is not clear, the query looks very simple. Insted of executig you can print the query and see how it is building.

Comment: Actually, i am not getting the desired out from above. i want either make a temporary table by getting all values from different table or to get values from all tables with same column name and types. Example as shown in the above asked question.

Answer (score 0):

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM ' SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',TABLE_NAME,' UNION ')
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema =? AND table_name LIKE 'Data_%'';

SET @a = 'MyDb';

EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
```

Comment: the above statements shows only tables names but in mine case i need the all tables data as shown in the question.

Comment: Pretty sure `PREPARE` is not SQL Server